# Fastest read WAV

Tags: r, wav, lapply

I am trying to find the length (in seconds) of all files (only wav) in a directory.

```
require(tuneR)
fnam=file.path("dir")
filist=list.files(fnam, recursive=TRUE, pattern="wav" )
filist1=paste(fnam, "/", filist, sep="")
nfiles=length(filist1)

x=1:nfiles
file_len=function(n){
  inname=data_phone$filist1[n]
  if(file.info(inname)$size!=0){
    ywave=readWave(inname)
    lengthSec=length(ywave@left)/ywave@samp.rate
  } else {
    lengthSec=0 
  }
}
len_file=unlist(lapply(x,FUN=file_len))
```

but it works really slowly with 86k files. Maybe there is another way to do it faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need the header for this. So I would do this:

```
library("tuneR")
filist <- list.files("dir", recursive=TRUE, pattern="\\.wav$", full.names = TRUE)

file_len <- function(fil) {
  if (file.info(fil)$size != 0) {
    wavHeader <- readWave(fil, header = TRUE)
    wavHeader$samples / wavHeader$sample.rate
  } else {
    0
  }
}
len_file <- sapply(filist, file_len)
```

I've also simplified and tidied your code, but the key change is to using the `header = TRUE` argument to readWave and then using the `$samples` and `$sample.rate` members of the list returned.